# How can I use CSS transition with CSS transform

Tags: html, css, angular, css-transitions

```
 .circular-menu.active .menu-item:nth-child(4) {
     transform: translate3d(-7em,1em,0);
     transition: ease;
          }
```

I got this code for my menu-item with a tag. The transform effect works but the transition won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a duration for your transition, otherwise by default it's 0s. Try this

```
.circular-menu.active .menu-item:nth-child(4) {
     transform: translate3d(-7em,1em,0);
     transition: all 0.3s ease;
 }
```

it'll animate all the effects you change with a duration of 300ms

Comment: I have already tried this piece of code but none of the transitions work. @Daniel

Comment: Strange, @ItoAr do you have another selector for that element without or with a different translate3d? Transitions work by "animating" the difference between the values of the same rule, i don't know if i'm explaining myself good enough. For example, let's say you have a `.box` div and a `.moved` selector with tre `transform` rule, now, when you add the `.moved` class to your `.box` div you should have the correct transition